# Word length count with for/if loop pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I need to count the word length from the column `Word` for each `Concept` separately depending on the `Note` column.

```
For each Concept in a df: 
  if Note contains ("tupi") -> count word length for these Words.    
  if not -> count word length for others

  print (Concept + " tupi " + word_length)
  print (Concept + " not tupi " + word_length)
```

And the output should be something like:

```
ANTEATER tupi 5.034

ANTEATER not tupi 4.56
_______
WILD CAT tupi 4.55

WILD CAT not tupi 3.44
```

Input dataframe example:

| Language | Concept | Word | Borrowing | Note |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | ANTEATER | tamanduá | YES | loan from tupi |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| Second | ANTEATER | uãiarú |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| Third | ANTEATER | atãn |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| Fourth | ANTEATER | aatãm | YES | loan from tupi |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| Fifth | WILD CAT | tamano | YES |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| Sixth | WILD CAT | sdfsg | YES |  |
| Seventh | WILD CAT | tamano | YES | loan from tupi |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| Eigth | WILD CAT | sdfsg | YES | loan from tupi |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this entirely in pandas without the need for a for-loop.

- Create a column `tupi` that represents if the `Note` column contains 'tupi' or not.
- Create a `Word Length` column with the length of the word in the `Word` column.

Now, use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and compute the average word length of each `Concept` with and without 'tupi' in the `Note` column:

```
df['tupi'] = df['Note'].str.contains('tupi').fillna(False)
df['Word Length'] = df['Word'].str.len()
df.groupby(['Concept', 'tupi'])['Word Length'].mean()
```

Resulting dataframe from the given data:

```
Concept   tupi 
ANTEATER  False    5.0
          True     6.5
WILD CAT  False    5.5
          True     5.5
```